# Why babel convert string interpolation into concat?

Tags: javascript, typescript, string, babeljs

Why babel convert string interpolation into concat?

if I have this code:

```
const to = "Cflower";
const from = "your script";
console.log(`Hello, ${to}! Greeting from ${from}`);
```

Babel compiles to:

```
var to = "Cflower";
var from = "your script";
console.log("Hello, ".concat(to, "! Greeting from ").concat(from));
```

TypeScript do the same thing. But the problem is, concat is slower than "+", MDN suggest to use "+" instant of concat, and also "+" string concat is available in es5, then why babel do that? Are there any purpose?

And I'm writing an app, performance is important, can I let babel generate "+" instead of concat for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earlier, Babel transpiled template literal expression and quasis with a `+` after [converting them to strings](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/5791). As a result, Symbols in template strings didn't throw an error.
This handling wasn't compatible with the specification so they changed the implementation to use concat.

Since then, the [transpiled output doesn't perform explicit conversion of the template literal expressions and quasis](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/6098)  to strings when using the `+` operator.

If you are on Babel 7.13.0 or higher, set the [`mutableTemplateObject`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/assumptions#mutabletemplateobject) in at the top level in your configuration to `true`.

```json
{
  "assumptions": {
    "mutableTemplateObject": true
  },
  ...
}
```

Otherwise, [set the loose option](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-template-literals#loose) for `@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals` to `true` to have the strings in template literal combined with the `+` operator.

```json
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: Good find, could you also address the "*then why babel do that?*" part of the question in your answer? (Just quote the docs)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll update that.